# Cloud Datastore: 503 service Unavailable with 1000/s+ concurrent transactions

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

When trying to save entities within a transaction to Datastore at a rate of ~1000 transactions per second or more, Datastore consistently returns 503 Service Unavailable until load backs off to a smaller rate.

I'm using the [python-datastore](https://github.com/googleapis/python-datastore) client library in a web service to save millions of unique entities to Datastore (**NOT** Firestore in Datastore mode).

I've tried using the recommended "500/50/5" rule to gradually ramp up to 1000 operations per second and more, but Datastore consistently peaks at the same level irrespective of how gradually the load is increased.

I've also observed that the same Datastore transaction operations are perfectly sustained at 750 operations per second without issues.

My understanding is Datastore can handle millions ops - does this also apply to transactional operations?
Are there any limits or constraints to using transactions when it comes to call volume.

Any suggestions or feedback as to how to tackle this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a sample data model for an "Offer" Kind that's written to Datastore. "id", a uuid, is the entity's key.

```
{
   "id": "a0cf7d66-5fab-495f-a73c-617570628fd6",
   "loyalty_id": "191200101829",
   "status": "eligible",
   "ce_promotion_id": "6452",
   "hybris_promotion_id": null,
   "offer_promotion_id": "47032",
   "ce_campaign_id": "0382",
   "promotion_type": "offer",
   "display_order": 1,
   "activation_date": null,
   "deactivation_date": null,
   "expiration_date": "2021-04-12T08:00:00Z",
   "scheduled_expiration_date": "2021-04-13T07:56:00Z",
   "redemption_date": null,
   "created_date": "2021-04-11T19:15:28.067053Z",
   "update_date": "2021-04-11T19:15:28.067083Z"
}
```

I also have 3 composite indexes:

1. loyalty_id ASC status ASC expiration_date DESC
2. status ASC scheduled_expiration_date DESC
3. loyalty_id ASC expiration_date DESC

Comment: It sounds like you're running into a [hotspot](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range) with your data model. In other words, your data model might be constraining the maximum write rate. Another possibility is contention between your transactions, depending on if they touch the same data.

Comment: If you post a sample data model and transaction, we can help further diagnose.

Comment: Thanks. I included a sample data model and indexes. Read through that part of the docs and a hotspot seems like a likely culprit - could it be the date properties in the composite indexes? The transaction is only for writing a single entity, but its purpose is to support rollback in case another unrelated operation happens to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the date properties increase or decrease monotonically, that would create a hotspot. To increase throughput, you would need to make the property non-monotonic when it's written to the database. Here's an approach from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#high_readwrite_rates_to_a_narrow_key_range):

> For instance, if you want to query for entries by timestamp but only
> need to return results for a single user at a time, you could prefix
> the timestamp with the user id and index that new property instead.
> This would still permit queries and ordered results for that user, but
> the presence of the user id would ensure the index itself is well
> sharded.

Another approach is to leave the property as is but turn off all indexes on that property (built-in, too) except those that add some randomness in front of the property. From your example, these indexes might fit that model if the `loyalty_id` is pretty random:

- loyalty_id ASC status ASC expiration_date DESC
- loyalty_id ASC expiration_date DESC

Note: Indexing order matters. It's important here that the monotonic property come last in the composite index.